# virtualenvwrapper and Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenvwrapper

I installed python 3.3.1 on ubuntu lucid and successfully created a virtualenv as below

```
virtualenv envpy331 --python=/usr/local/bin/python3.3
```

this created a folder `envpy331` on my home dir.

I also have `virtualenvwrapper` installed.But in the docs only `2.4-2.7` versions of `python` are supported..Has anyone tried to  organize the `python3` virtualenv ? If so, can you tell me how ?

Comment: The problem with that is that pip is still the python2 pip, isn't it? I think what you want is virtualenvwrapper to use `pyvenv` instead of `virtualenv`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [latest version of virtualenvwrapper](https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper/overview) is tested under Python3.2. Chances are good it will work with Python3.3 too.

Answer (score 253):

If you already have python3 installed as well virtualenvwrapper the only thing you would need to do to use python3 with the virtual environment is creating an environment using:

```
which python3 #Output: /usr/bin/python3
mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 nameOfEnvironment
```

Or, (at least on OSX using brew):

```
mkvirtualenv --python=`which python3` nameOfEnvironment
```

Start using the environment and you'll see that as soon as you type python you'll start using python3

Comment: Didn't quite work for me on OSX with 2.7.8 and 3.4.1 installed side-by-side via brew. Modifying it to "mkvirtualenv --python=\`which python3\` nameOfEnvironment" worked perfectly, though.

Comment: @ChrisDoggett same on Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: On Ubuntu the command will be: mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 your-env-name

Comment: If you use bash, you can do substitution to save a line - `mkvirtualenv --python=$(which python3) nameOfEnvironment`

Comment: what's really great is to create the following bash alias `alias mkvirtualenv3="mkvirtualenv --python=$(which python3.6)"` - then it's easy to create virtualenvs for python 2 or 3

Comment: If you want to use `which python3` or `$(which python3)` make sure you ARE NOT in another virtualenv -- or you'll get a virtual path to python 3 which isn't really what you want, i.e. `~/.virtualenvs/the_other_env/bin/python3`

Comment: I'm getting error `ImportError: No module named virtualenv`. I have python 3.7 installed beside python 2.7.15

Comment: @Mikebarson You have to pip install virtualenv, it's not a built in module.

Answer (score 53):

You can make virtualenvwrapper use a custom Python binary instead of the one virtualenvwrapper is run with. To do that you need to use VIRTUALENV_PYTHON variable which is utilized by virtualenv:

```
$ export VIRTUALENV_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
$ mkvirtualenv -a myproject myenv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3
New python executable in myenv/bin/python3
Also creating executable in myenv/bin/python
(myenv)$ python
Python 3.2.3 (default, Oct 19 2012, 19:53:16) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: This is effectively out of date. Rather than setting an environment variable you should use the --python parameter that is currently suggested by Jonathan.

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins Why? This prevents having to specify the python version for each new env.

Comment: @Joost That's a fair point. I personally feel like that's a downside but I can see why people would prefer that.

Answer (score 23):

On Ubuntu; using `mkvirtualenv -p python3 env_name` loads the virtualenv with python3.

Inside the env, use `python --version` to verify.

Comment: `python --version` to display the version

Answer (score 22):

virtualenvwrapper now lets you specify the python executable without the path.

So (on OSX at least)`mkvirtualenv --python=python3 nameOfEnvironment` will suffice.

Comment: Needs an two dashes. Would edit, but SE requires 6 characters and the change only needs one.

Answer (score 22):

You can add this to your .bash_profile or similar:

```
alias mkvirtualenv3='mkvirtualenv --python=`which python3`'
```

Then use `mkvirtualenv3` instead of `mkvirtualenv` when you want to create a python 3 environment.

Answer (score 13):

I find that running

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

and

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/bin/virtualenv-3.4
```

in the command line on Ubuntu forces mkvirtualenv to use python3 and virtualenv-3.4. One still has to do

```
mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 nameOfEnvironment
```

to create the environment. This is assuming that you have python3 in /usr/bin/python3 and virtualenv-3.4  in /usr/local/bin/virtualenv-3.4.

Comment: Just use `which python2.4` or `which python3.5` or `which python3.6` to find the directory for `--python=DIRECTORY`

Answer (score 5):

This [post](https://bitbucket.org/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper/issues/167/virtualenvwrapper_get_site_packages_dir-is) on the bitbucket issue tracker of [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) may be of interest.
It is mentioned there that most of virtualenvwrapper's functions work with the [venv](http://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) virtual environments in Python 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

I added `export VIRTUALENV_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3` to my `~/.bashrc` like this:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENV_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

then run `source .bashrc`

and you can specify the python version for each new env `mkvirtualenv --python=python2 env_name`