# Installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper: Python says no module named virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Lots of other threads about similar issues, but none that I could find where quite the same case as mine. So, here goes:

**Things I did:**

- Ran: `sudo easy_install pip`
- Ran: `sudo pip install virtualenv`
- Ran: `sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper`

**Current State:**

- .bash_profile

  ```
  export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
  export PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE=$HOME/.pip/cache
  export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
  export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME
  export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
  ```
- Running `mkvirtualenv test` results in:

  ```
  New python executable in trunk/bin/python
  Installing setuptools, pip...done.
  /usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
  ```
- Manually inspecting '/usr/local/bin' shows that virtualenvwrapper.sh exists
- Unlike some other questions I saw about this, I get no message about virtualenvwrapper when I start a new terminal window
- Running 'which python' results in: `/usr/bin/python`

**What I've tried:**

- Inspecting my path to make sure it looks like it is supposed to
- Reinstalling pip, then using the reinstalled pip to reinstall virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper

Any help getting this working would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is your default version of Python? Pip will install to whatever Python version is the current default (2.7, 3.3). If you install a package for say Python 2.7 you cannot use it in Python 3.3 . Double check that the `/usr/bin/python` directory is where your default version of Python is located.

Comment: I was under the impression that 'which python' did that and it returned /usr/bin/python. Is that not correct?

Answer (score 89):

I've managed to get this working after having the same problem you've described here by editing my **~/.bash_profile** and adding this:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/code/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/code
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS='--no-site-packages'

source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Save, close.

then:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

and:

```
$ mkvirtualenv test
```

Comment: On MacOS `/usr/local/bin/python` is the one installed by `brew`. `/usr/bin/python` is the one from the system. It's easier to use python from `brew` with `virtualenvwrapper` so `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python` is the important part here.  You can also install `python3` with `brew` and use `/usr/local/bin/python3` instead if you prefer .

Comment: @GabLeRoux thanks for that compressed Answer in comment.

Answer (score 41):

I had the same problem setting up virtualenvwrapper on ubuntu.

I had installed virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper using pip which installed these modules in the site package of python3.5. How did I find that out?

Open your terminal and type

```
$ pip --version
```

**pip 9.0.1 from /home/clyton/.virtualenvs/test1/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)**

Then I checked the variable `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` whose value was
/usr/bin/python. 
On your terminal and type

```
$ ls -l $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Dec 10  2015 **/usr/bin/python -> python2.7**
```

As you can see this variable is pointing to python2.7 and you may have installed virtualenv in a different python site package.

So to fix this problem, just add the below line in your bashrc

```
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.5
```

**NOTE:** Set the above value to the python version with which virtualenv was installed. In my case it was python3.5 so I have set that value. How to find out the python version used to install virtualenv? Again type `pip --version` in the terminal.

Then open a new shell session and try mkvirtualenv again. This time it should work.

Answer (score 15):

If you take a look at the *virtualenvwrapper.sh* script, you will find these lines:

```
# Locate the global Python where virtualenvwrapper is installed.
if [ "$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON" = "" ] 
then
    VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="$(command \which python)"
fi
```

If you don't manually export `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER` appropriately for your version of python, it will assume the system default where you don't have the *virtualenvwrapper* package installed.

I fixed this like so:

```
echo "export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=$(which python3.6)" >> ~/.zshrc
```

This is all documented on the official website [here](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#configuration).

Answer (score 7):

try installing virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper with `pip2 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper`. it seems like pip install virtualenv and it's wrapper to python 3 as it's default

Comment: I used this solution and fixed my problem without me messing with the `~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, adding this line into my .zshrc file did the trick,

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python2.7
```

remember to source ~/.zshrc to update the change to your current terminal.

Comment: Same issue, don't get why, just tired wasting my time. Using `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14_2/bin/python2.7` did the trick, thanks

Comment: In my case the issue was that it was using python2 which didn't have virtualenvwrapper installed. Editing virtualenvwrapper.sh and changing the path like so worked: `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="$(command \which python3)"`

Answer (score 3):

Got this error after recently (summer 2017) updating Homebrew and python. The issue in my case was that Homebrew no longer overwrites the system python and I didn't have `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` installed for the system python.

The solution in my case was to add the following to `~/.bash_profile` (or  `~/.zshrc`):

`export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"`

This made `python` point to the brew version of python and also gave me `pip` back. This version of `python` had `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` installed so the error no longer appeared. See the caveats section under `brew info python` and https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/15746 for more information

Answer (score 2):

Try to uninstall your `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` and install it again using `pip` (check if you symlink your pip or assigned an alias on it for other version) in version 2.7 (I think).

I encountered the same error and I just did this and solved my problem.

I using Ubuntu machine.

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's relevant to anyone but I got this error while editing `~/.zshrc` while virtualenv being active. So I had to `deactivate` and then `rmvirtualenv env_name` to remove the errors. And then I recreated the env: `mkvirtaulenv env_name` and `workon env_name` and this time I got no errors.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this thread is super old but I got stuck on it while trying to find a solution to this problem (using `pip3` but you can swap `pip` as necessary).
I ended up using a modified version of a solution that I found in another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29486113/problems-with-python-and-virtualenvwrapper-after-updating-no-module-named-virtu/38580003#38580003).
Add the following to your `.zshrc`/`.bashrc`:

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
```

> I had to add `local` in the above but guessing that whether or not you need to do so will depend on your
> installation. I realized I was referencing the wrong location because
> I was getting this error: `zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/bin/python3` so I just did `which python3` to see where it lived.

Make sure you uninstall any existing versions of `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` as you can not simply install to a new location with an existing version on your machine, you must delete the old version and then install the new version in the new location.

To install:
`sudo /usr/local/bin/pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper`

And, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123459/virtualenvwrapper-and-python-3) post, you should be able to create a virtual environment with your version of python3 using this command:

```sh
mkvirtualenv --python=`which python3` nameOfEnvironment
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.xx, virtual env can be created only by specifying python executable path.

```
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
$ mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python <name_of_your_virtual_env>
```