# problems with python and virtualenvwrapper after updating: No module named virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I run python 2.7.6 with virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper under ubuntu 14.04.
now i have installed python 2.7.9 from source. the new python interpreter is now located under `/usr/local/bin` but it seems the old interpreter is also located under `/usr/bin`.

if I run python shell it shows up python2.7.9. but if I use `mkvirtualenv venv` I am getting the following message.

> New python executable in venv/bin/python
>   Installing setuptools, pip...done.
>   Blockquote /usr/local/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper

old `.bashrc` (with working configuration using python 2.7.6 interpreter)

```
# virtualenv-wrappper path
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

new `.bashrc` (with failure configuration)

```
# virtualenv-wrappper path
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

with the new `.baschrc` I type in `source .bashrc` and get the following output.

> /usr/local/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
>       virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.
>
> If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
>       check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
>       VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python and that PATH is
>       set properly.

And I have also tried `which -a python`:

**output:**

```
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

I want to use python 2.7.9 with virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper. so what I have to do to get this running ?

Comment: Have you installed virtualenvwrapper under python 2.7.9?

Comment: yes i have reinstalled both virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper under python2.7.9. give me the same results.

Comment: if you try to import virtualenvwrapper from python (2.7.9) shell, do you get any error? And what if you try to create the virtualenv with `-p path/to/python/interpreter`?

Comment: @Railslide: tried to import it from python shell as you said give me an error. ImportError: No module named virtualenvwrapper. same with virtualenv.

Comment: How did you install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper?

Comment: sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to install them under python 2.7.9 by specifying the path to correct version of pip to be used

```
/usr/local/bin/pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

otherwise, when running `pip install` the sytem will use the default one (i.e. the one located at `/usr/bin/pip`)

Answer (score 48):

If you have modified your `virtualenvwrapper` to point to `python3`, like I do, add the following line in your `.bashrc` file :

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

making sure that it's placed ***before*** the following line (if you have it):

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Then, make sure you install the `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` using:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

Comment: Someone should make doing this simpler. Just one command and you have it all.

Comment: @KibeCollins Yeah you're right. And it ~should~ be using Python3 by default, but NOOooooo..

Comment: This might also be useful: https://medium.com/@gitudaniel/installing-virtualenvwrapper-for-python3-ad3dfea7c717

Comment: Thank you for this. Out of all the other posts, this was the actual fix.

Answer (score 0):

`source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh`

---

when use pyenv:

```
export PYENV_ROOT="${HOME}/.pyenv"

if [ -d "${PYENV_ROOT}" ]; then
    export PATH="${PYENV_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}"
    eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
export PATH

export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT=/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
#important
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh
```