# virtualenvwrapper -- Opencv 3.1.0 installation error

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to install opencv 3.1.0 by the help of following [blog](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/)(Why? Because I followed the same blog to install opencv in Desktop, but In my Laptop, following issue came)

Here I encountered the following error as --

```
ujjal@ujjaldas223:~$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
/home/ujjal/anaconda2/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/home/ujjal/anaconda2/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

I followed the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29486113/problems-with-python-and-virtualenvwrapper-after-updating-no-module-named-virtu), but failed to resolve issue.
Suggest me how to solve this error.
I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS both in Desktop and laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it!
The problem was anaconda path appended to python.
Removing anaconda2 completely solved the issue.