# Virtualenvwrapper: no module named virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to get virtualenvwrapper running.
I install it with:

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

I edited the .bashrc like this:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT=/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

When I try to run "source ~/.bashrc" I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

I installed pip, python and virtualenv in the following directories:

```
which python
/usr/bin/python

which pip
/usr/bin/pip

which virtualenv
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What the os environment variable `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` equals to? Try to set it as the error tells you: `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python`

Comment: When I add this in my .bashrc, the error still remains the same

Comment: Have you restarted your shell after adding it to bashrc?

Comment: yes, if I change from tcsh to bash it immediately shows the same error message

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: I have installed python 2.7.9 and 3.4.2, but in my virtualenv I use the 3.4.2

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to

```
pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

and add this to your ~/.bashrc file

```
 export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

This is because your virtualenvwrapper is pointing to python3. I just resolved mine now. Thanks to [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38580003/5197022)

Answer (score 1):

Your error happens because you installed virtualenv for Python 2.7, but you try use it with Python 3. Use *pip3* to install Python 3 packages on multi-version system.

```
pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper
pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

Comment: Check the output for `python -v`. That's the default one, which points to `/usr/bin/python`. This error usually indicates version conflicts. If it says 2.7, then use pip install for both virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper modules. Else use pip3 to install both.

Comment: @ChenA. To check for python version, instead of small "v", it should be capital "V": `python -V`

Answer (score 1):

You need to `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` in your `.bashrc` (you don't need to export it).