# Issue installing Virtualenvwrapper on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python-3.6, ubuntu-18.04, virtualenvwrapper

Fresh Ubuntu 18.04 install. Following [these instructions](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) here are the commands I've run so far.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
python3 -V 
sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev
sudo apt install python3-venv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Returns

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory.

find virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Returns

```
find: ‘virtualenvwrapper.sh’: No such file or directory
```

EDIT:

```
Sudo -H pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

didn't solve the issue either.

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38580003/1316725) that sovled the issue.

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

then make sure to install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper with:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

You may have to use sudo's -H flag like I did for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

on Ubuntu 18.04 I had to add this to my .bash_profile

```
# virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenv
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_LOG_DIR="$WORKON_HOME"
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR="$WORKON_HOME"
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
source ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Then run source ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 1):

You've installed `python3`, `pip` and `venv` but not `virtualenvwrapper`. Install it with `pip`:

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

Purge and reinstall pip first.

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pip
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Then install virtualenvwrapper:

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```