# Issues with virtualenvwrapper after upgrading brew

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, homebrew, virtualenvwrapper

I upgraded brew and now I'm getting this message every time I open the terminal:

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

I tried the suggested solutions posted by Railslide and Sudipta Basak from the following post, but neither are fixing this issue for me: [problems with python and virtualenvwrapper after updating: No module named virtualenvwrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29486113/problems-with-python-and-virtualenvwrapper-after-updating-no-module-named-virtu)

Executing "/usr/local/bin/pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper" gives me the "Requirement already satisfied" message.

I'm on Mac, and this is breaking a few things for me, like Juypter Notebook that I had installed with Anaconda, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What version of Python are you actually running in your default shell?

Comment: @Makoto Version 2.7.10

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` give you and what order is your Python executables (e.g. does Python 2 come before Python 3)?

Comment: Running `echo $PATH` is giving me `usr/bin/sudo:/Users/_myName_/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. This may be a silly question, but how do I check the order of my Python executables? Looking in /usr/bin/, I am seeing `python`. Looking in /usr/local/bin/, I see `python3` as Alias.

Comment: If Python 2 is in `/usr/bin` and Python 3 is in `/usr/local/bin`, then `/usr/local/bin` needs to come before `/usr/bin` in your `PATH`.  Seeing Python 3 as an *alias* (and aliases have very explicit meanings in \*nix) could be problematic.

Comment: Do you think that's the reason why I'm getting this error message for virtualenvwrapper? Any recommendations on the steps I should take next?

Comment: It's been a moment since I've dealt with brew installations, but I would imagine that you want your brew path to be the first thing on your `PATH` as opposed to `/usr/bin/sudo`.  That'd be about the only thing I could think of from here.

Comment: @Makoto Thanks. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `virtualenvwrapper` for the instance of `pip` that goes along with the instance of `python` that you are using.

For example, my `~/.zprofile` contains these setup commands:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/opt/homebrew/bin/virtualenv
source /opt/homebrew/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Because I am using `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`, I need to use the corresponding version of pip:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```