# /usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, bash, macos, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

`Admins-MacBook-Air-34:~ USER$ workon waterbutler
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
(waterbutler) Admins-MacBook-Air-34:~ USER$ deactivate
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
Admins-MacBook-Air-34:~ USER$ usr/bin/python pip install virtualenvwrapper
-bash: usr/bin/python: No such file or directory`

The problem I am having is that it keeps telling me that I haven't installed virtualenvwrapper when I have installed it and whenever I run the pip install virtualenvwrapper, it says it's already satisfied.

Comment: `Admins-MacBook-Air-34:~ brianaguirre$ pip freeze
invoke==0.13.0
MacFSEvents==0.7
pbr==3.0.1
six==1.10.0
stevedore==1.23.0
virtualenv==15.1.0
virtualenv-clone==0.2.6
virtualenvwrapper==4.7.2`

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct version of python and pip?

Comment: Ran $ pip install -U pip 
Tells me: `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` 

And I have installed the latest version of python, which I use in my virtualenv.

Comment: It seems you have 2 pythons: /usr/bin/python and /usr/local/bin/python (please verify) and pip uses the latter while workon uses the former. Perhaps you need to rearrange entries in PATH env var to put /usr/local/bin before /usr/bin — then workon should use /usr/local/bin/python.

Comment: I was able to solve it using this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997403/installed-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper-python-says-no-module-named-virtuale/25583193#25583193