# Cannot run Python module

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to run the Python 3 module '3to2' on Windows 10. Here is part of my `pip3 list`:

```
Package                       Version
----------------------------- -----------
3to2                          1.1.1
```

I am trying to execute it with `py -3 -m 3to2`, but am receiving this:

```
C:\Users\Ben Bistline\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: No module named 3to2
```

I think it has something to do with my Python Path, but I am unsure.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34168019/how-to-use-3to2

Answer (score 0):

There is no module called 3to2.  Module names can't start with a digit.  Instead, there should be a standalone file in your "...\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts"
directory called `3to2.py`.  That's what you need to run.